# Posting a Grid's data from view to the Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

How do you post a grid's data from the View to the Controller? I would like to find out how to do it so that the model, when posted to the controller, would bring the grid data with it.

If I have this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DetailModel> Details { get; protected set; }
}
```

and I'm displaying it on a grid. I want to be able to take it when I post `ViewModel` back to the controller like so

```
[HttpPost]
public void Save(ViewModel model)
{
    repository.SaveDetails(model.Details);
}
```

I'm currently using MVCContrib's grid, but should a snippet be able to do this, any other grid implementation should be able to apply it too even MVC's default Detail template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show this data to the grid you must have fetched it from somewhere. So why posting it? Simply send some `id` and re-fetch it from the same datasource. On the other hand if your grid allows the user to modify the data, you would normally use an HTML `<form>` with input fields.

As far as binding is concerned here's a [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) which explains how the request parameters should be named in order to be able to successfully reconstruct the view model in the post action.

Comment: I'm trying out the blog post. I didn't get the part on form input fields though. Does that mean one form element per cell? Where do I store each edit that the user does on the grid? I don't want his edits to persist until he's made all the changes and clicked on the submit button.